# Unable to connect to remote server with SSH

Tags: server, ssh

I used to connect to my server without any problem using `ssh` on `Ubuntu` with this command:

```
ssh username@server-ip
```

I can no longer do it now I've changed my location (same PC).

whene I run the same command using the `-v` parameter, it outputs me this:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xxx [xx.xx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

and then after a while:

```
Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

what is the problem, and how can I solve it ?

EDIT: ps: it works on `PuTTY`, but not with `OpenSSH`

Comment: The server you're opening a session with, have you configured it in the past to only accept requests from specific IPs?

Comment: and do you have physical access now?

Comment: @Colyn1337: not configured for that.

Comment: @Achu: No, only remote access

Comment: This looks to me like a server-side problem. Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini It works with `PuTTY` when connecting with `ssh`

Comment: Yes, I've read it. However the problem is that it's the server which closes the connection, not the client. Therefore the server must know why it is doing so. Probably the client is doing something the server doesn't like... the problem is: who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-c aes128-ctr` to the command line, and/or disabling ECDSA keys. If this helps, you may be bitten by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/708493).